# php shell_exec can't read gammu configuration file

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, gammu

I want to gammu to identify my modem on ubuntu 12.04 with shell_exec() command...I have read many same problem like i have in many forum that suggest its about system privillages, and its true I cannot run `gammu --identify` without sudo..its always say cannot open specified file, I tried edit sudoers, adduser to dialout groups, and not working..

Finally desperate measure i chown every gammu related file to my user and it work, i can run `gammu --identify` without sudo..the problem is I tried the same way to make it run with shell_exec() but it always say cannot open specified file.

Can anyone help me to fix this please...
How to know where is the error??
Thanks in advance..

Comment: This *is* bad practice. But if there's no other way and your code is stored safely, try http://php.net/manual/en/book.expect.php. You could insert your sudo password get actually run the command correctly. I'm not pro-this tho, but sometimes there's no other way.

Comment: @Allendar: thank u for the answer..yeah i read about that method too..but i want to avoid that way the most, is there no other way??

Comment: I'm afraid not. A command isn't protected by `sudo` for nothing. The command wants to do something (or access) something that's usually off-limits for normal users. If you want to protect your environment from not using `sudo` you might want to write a Bash script that's outside your webroot that does the command with sudo and writes the output to a file your PHP installation can access. This way you ensure it's impossible for a hacker to get your `sudo` password, but your PHP app can then access the information you need. The bash script could run on crontab to generate every X-seconds.

Comment: @Allendar: ok thank u for ur answer..i'll try to make it like your suggestion...thanks for the help